# I am been trying to use vim and nano command to create file in docker, but i keep getting this

Tags: docker

```
root@yash:/home/yashvardhan# docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
root@1546619214e6:/# vim /tmp/testfile
bash: vim: command not found
root@1546619214e6:/# sudo vim /tmp/testfile
bash: sudo: command not found
```

Answer (score 3):

The Ubuntu docker image does not have vim installed by default. After running a container for the Ubuntu docker image, you can install vim:

```
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
apt update
apt install vim
```

Note that `sudo` is not required since you are root by default in the docker container.